# Unable to find wine windows program loader even after installing wine

Tags: 18.04, wine

I have installed wine in my ubuntu 18.4 , After installing wine through terminal I checked it's version using :-

```
wine --version
```

From the above CLI I get output as:

> wine-3.0 (Ubuntu 3.0-1ubuntu1)

when I am trying to open flstudio.exe I am unable to find wine windows program loader at select application popup.

[image]

hints :-

when I write **winecfg** on terminal one window popups which have options like graphic , audio etc

Problem :-

How can I get wine windows program loader on select application popup?

Answer (score 1):

It happens most of the time when you install wine from the software center.

I would suggest to remove your current version and install by using the command

> sudo apt install winehq-stable

Last time I checked it installs the wine--4.0 version. If everything fails then I would suggest you follow guide provided by [WineHQ Wiki](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You can open it using the terminal.

for example if your file(`flstudio.exe`) is in the desktop, use the following code:

```
 wine /User/Desktop/flstudio.exe
```

Here is an easier way: If your file is in for example the images folder, just open that folder, click the right button of the mouse and click in "Open in terminal". Then the terminal will be open with the images direction. You just have to write this, and it will be open.

```
 wine flstudio.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `wine-binfmt` package:

```
sudo apt install wine-binfmt
```